# Unable to retrieve all fields from user table with app.user using TWIG and Symfony 2, FOSUserBundle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I am currently making a website and I have an entity User, which has several fields. But when I am trying retrieve the current user that is logged in it only retrieves the username.

Fields in UserType are as follows:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('name')
            ->add('building')
            ->add('room')
        ;
    }
```

I am using this html code and TWIG to retrieve the fields:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Building</th>
                <th>Room Number</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ app.user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ app.user.building }}</td>
                <td>{{ app.user.room }}</td>
                <td>{{ app.user.email }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

But when I view table in the browser I only get the email field populated in the table?

User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace FYProject\ProjectBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fyp_user")
 */

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $school;


    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $qualification;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $modeofstudy;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $programmecode;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $programmeyear;

    /**
     * @var datetime
     */
    protected $startdate;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $building;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $room;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * Set school
     *
     * @param string $school
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setSchool($school)
    {
        $this->school = $school;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get school
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSchool()
    {
        return $this->school;
    }

    /**
     * set qualification
     *
     * @param string qualification
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setQualification($qualification){

        $this->qualification = $qualification;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get qualification
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQualification(){

        return $this->qualification;
    }

    /**
     * set modeofstudy
     *
     * @param string modeofstudy
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setModeofstudy($modeofstudy){

        $this->modeofstudy = $modeofstudy;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get modeofstudy
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getModeofstudy(){

        return $this->modeofstudy;
    }

    /**
     * set programmecode
     *
     * @param string programmecode
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setProgrammecode($programmecode){

        $this->programmecode = $programmecode;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get programmecode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProgrammecode(){

        return $this->programmecode;
    }

    /**
     * set programmeyear
     *
     * @param integer programmeyearn
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setProgrammeyear($programmeyear){

        $this->programmecode = $programmeyear;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get programmecode
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getProgrammeyear(){

        return $this->programmeyear;
    }

    /**
     * set startdate
     *
     * @param datetime startdate
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setStartdate($startdate){

        $this->startdate = $startdate;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get startdate
     *
     * @return datetime
     */
    public function getStartdate(){

        return $this->startdate;
    }

    /**
     * set lastname
     *
     * @param string lastname
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname){

        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get lastname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastname(){

        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * set building
     * @param string building
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setBuilding($building){

        $this->building = $building;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get building
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBuilding(){

        return $this->building;
    }

    /**
     * set room
     * @param integer room
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setRoom($room){

        $this->room = $room;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get room
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRoom(){

        return $this->room;
    }

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

When registering the current fields are returning null, using dump(app.user):

```
 User {#306 ▼
  #id: 9
  #name: null
  #lastname: null
  #school: null
  #qualification: null
  #modeofstudy: null
  #programmecode: null
  #programmeyear: null
  #startdate: null
  #building: null
  #room: null
```

Comment: Are you sure you extended the [User entity correctly?](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-3-create-your-user-class)

Comment: @bassplayer7 I have class user extends BaseUser, i cant see what i am missing even following the documentation. I was missing the parent: __construct method but even with that it does not work?

Comment: did you update your database using the doctrine:schema:update? update your question with your entity user

Comment: Yeah i did, i have updated question with the User entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved

I wasnt setting the @ORM\column for each field in the Entity User. Updated User Entity:

```
    <?php

namespace FYProject\ProjectBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fyp_user")
 */

class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     *
     */

    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="school", type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $school;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="qualification", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $qualification;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="modeofstudy", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $modeofstudy;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="programmecode", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $programmecode;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="programmeyear", type="integer", length=10)
     */
    protected $programmeyear;

    /**
     * @var datetime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="startdate", type="datetime", length=50)
     */
    protected $startdate;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="building", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $building;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="room", type="integer", length=50)
     */
    protected $room;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }



    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * Set school
     *
     * @param string $school
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setSchool($school)
    {
        $this->school = $school;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get school
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSchool()
    {
        return $this->school;
    }

    /**
     * set qualification
     *
     * @param string $qualification
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setQualification($qualification){

        $this->qualification = $qualification;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get qualification
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getQualification(){

        return $this->qualification;
    }

    /**
     * set modeofstudy
     *
     * @param string $modeofstudy
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setModeofstudy($modeofstudy){

        $this->modeofstudy = $modeofstudy;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get modeofstudy
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getModeofstudy(){

        return $this->modeofstudy;
    }

    /**
     * set programmecode
     *
     * @param string $programmecode
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setProgrammecode($programmecode){

        $this->programmecode = $programmecode;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get programmecode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getProgrammecode(){

        return $this->programmecode;
    }

    /**
     * set programmeyear
     *
     * @param integer $programmeyear
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setProgrammeyear($programmeyear){

        $this->programmecode = $programmeyear;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get programmecode
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getProgrammeyear(){

        return $this->programmeyear;
    }

    /**
     * set startdate
     *
     * @param datetime $startdate
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setStartdate($startdate){

        $this->startdate = $startdate;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get startdate
     *
     * @return datetime
     */
    public function getStartdate(){

        return $this->startdate;
    }

    /**
     * set lastname
     *
     * @param string $lastname
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname){

        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get lastname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastname(){

        return $this->lastname;
    }

    /**
     * set building
     * @param string $building
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setBuilding($building){

        $this->building = $building;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get building
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBuilding(){

        return $this->building;
    }

    /**
     * set room
     * @param integer $room
     * @return Entity
     */
    public function setRoom($room){

        $this->room = $room;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * get room
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRoom(){

        return $this->room;
    }

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Problem Solved! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this docummentation to override a Form Type
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

Update your database schema

Clear your cache